# JSON and Realm — do I have to maintain separate structs / classes?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, realm

When I receive JSON from an API call, when decoding it I have structs like this:

```swift
import Foundation

struct JSON: Codable {
    
    var alpha: Alpha
    var beta: Beta
    var gamma: [Gamma]?
    
}
```

I want to save the JSON in my Realm database, to later use and traverse like JSON. It's my understanding that I can't just use the existing structs I have written, instead I have to rewrite a second (similar) class like this to use with Realm:

```swift
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class RealmJSON: Object, Identifiable {
    
    @Persisted (primaryKey: true) var id: ObjectId
    
    @Persisted var alpha: RealmAlpha
    @Persisted var beta: RealmBeta
    @Persisted var gamma: RealmSwift.List<RealmGamma>?
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        "id"
    }
    
    convenience init(id: ObjectId, alpha: RealmAlpha, beta: RealmBeta, gamma: RealmSwift.List<RealmGamma>?) {
        
        self.init()
        
        self.id = id
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
        self.gamma = gamma
    }
    
}
```

Obviously, this is inconvenient especially when dealing with large amounts of JSON. Moreover I want to use Swagger codegen to write the client code for me, but it kind of defeats the purpose if I then have to manually add the Realm classes manually.

Is this the only way for dealing with JSON and a Realm database, or am I missing something here?

EDIT: I realise a simple way is to store most of the JSON as a raw JSON string with properties to identify schema type / version. Then I can just fetch the correct schema I require and parse the rawJSON string with the existing JSON structs...

Comment: I am not sure the question or objective is clear. The code in your question would easily handle JSON data and once the object is created in code, you are good to go. What specifically is inconvenient about it? You have two sample classes in the question which are basically the same, with the RealmJSON Object being managed by Realm - perhaps you want to avoid the `convenience init` in the Realm object? Why not make that object conform to codable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the json data directly to your objects. I can think of two ways.

The first way, conform to `Codable`.

```
class Dog: Object, Codable {
    @Persisted var name: String
}

class Cat: Object, Codable {
    @Persisted var name: String
}

class Kid: Object, Codable {
    @Persisted var name: String
}

class Owner: Object, Codable {
    @Persisted var name: String
    @Persisted var dog: Dog?
    @Persisted var cat: Cat?
    @Persisted var kids: List<Kid>
}
```

Let's use the following method to make json data:

```
func makeData() -> Data {
    let string = """
        {
            "name": "Tom",
            "kids": [{"name": "Penelope"}, {"name": "Rob"}],
            "cat": {"name": "Lilly"},
            "dog": {"name": "Lucy"}
        }
    """
    return string.data(using: .utf8)!
}
```

Now we can create our objects:

```
func decodeOwner() {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let owner = try! decoder.decode(Owner.self, from: makeData())
    print("Decoded:", owner)
}
```

Another way is to use JSONSerialization and use the result to pass to the value constructor:

```
extension Object {
    convenience init(json: Data) throws {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json)
        self.init(value: data)
    }
}

func serializeOwner() {
    let owner = try! Owner(json: makeData())
    print("Serialization:", owner)
}
```